# How to always call constructor of current class, even in a derived class?

Tags: c#, class, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

If I run the following C# code, it only outputs `BaseClass() called`, which is understandable. However, what if I wanted `BaseClass.CreateInstance()` to always return an instance of the class it's being called on, even if that's actually a different class that inherits that method?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Example
{
    class BaseClass
    {
        public BaseClass()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BaseClass() called");
        }

        public static BaseClass CreateInstance()
        {
            return new BaseClass();
        }
    }

    class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
        public DerivedClass()
            : base()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DerivedClass() called");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DerivedClass.CreateInstance();
            Console.ReadLine(); //pause so output is readable
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: static members do not take part in virtual inheritance. That concept would not make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're actually not calling it on `DerivedClass`.  The compiler sees that there is a static method on `BaseClass` (and not `DerivedClass`) and automatically converts that into a call to `BaseClass.CreateInstance`.

One option would be to use generics to handle this:

```
public static T CreateInstance<T>() where T : BaseClass, new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

This would allow you to write:

```
DerivedClass dc = BaseClass.CreateInstance<DerivedClass>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not creating an instance of `DerivedClass` in your `CreateInstance` method, so you're not getting one back, hence it's constructor is not called.

If you were to do `var bla = new DerivedClass()` it would call its constructor.